# Filename and path link in batch

Tags: windows, bash, syntax, filenames, ogr2ogr

So I have a line of code in .bat using ogr2ogr geospatial tool:

> for /R %F in (*_gpx.shp) do ogr2ogr -update -append "%~dpnF.shp" "______________"

In the "___________"space I need to specify a file, that:

-is in the same folder as *_gpx.shp

-beginning of its name is equal to the *gpx.shp*, but the ending is not (it's a pair of "*sametext_abc_gpx.shp*" and "*sametext_bby.shp*")

-I have plenty of these pairs and their names aren't of same length, but have same endings (only *abc* and *bby*)

My first guess was

> "*_bby.shp"

But it didn't work for me. I tried with addressing it with *%~dpF*, removing last 7 characters ("*abc_gpx*") and adding "*bby*", but I'm not so fluent in bash syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that appeared to be the solution:

> "%~dpF*_bby.shp"

for Windows CMD, for batch files obviously

> "%%~dpF*_bby.shp"

That is **d**isk letter, **p**ath and letter indicating **F**ile which is a wildcard `*` plus the ending.